# Ideal op-amp used as a digital buffer: rise time

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer, rise-time, slew-rate

[image]

Vo = Vin, so the rise time for both should be the same, but the capacitor takes some time charging.

How can I find the charging time without any other information here?

Comment: The charging time is proportional to R*C.  What is the R of an ideal opamp output?

Comment: All the information is in the word "ideal". What is the dv/dt of an ideal op-amp?

Comment: Since the input rise time is not zero, you don't have a paradox. You can calculate the required output current from your ideal op-amp.

Comment: For ideal opamp rise time is 0, so as soon as the input changes output will change. That means answer should be 0. Is that correct?

Comment: @sheetal No. The *rise time* is not zero for the ideal op amp, but the *max. slew rate* is infinite. This means that the ideal opamp follower *always* will satisfy `Vo = Vin` as you correctly write.

Comment: @tobalt Okay, got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @tobalt pointed out, if "slew-rate" is infinite for an ideal op-amp, the output will always "follow" the "input" (Also, output impedance = 0).

Note that, in the "real world", the output follows input ... until the "capacitor" become too big. And then, the output impedance of the op-amp also "slew" down the rate of output ... as can be seen in this simulation.

[image]

Note also that op-amp can become "unstable" ... As in this case ...

[image]